# export highcharts to png in IE >5.0, Chrome, Firefox.

Tags: .net, highcharts

How to export Highchart in "png" formate in IE >6.0, Chrome, Firefox.
I do not want to send a request on Highchart server to convert it on "png" or any other formate due to security issue.

Thanks
Abhishek Singh

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own export server which the HighCharts team documents [here](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts) or use one of the many wrappers for your flavor of code listed [here](http://www.highcharts.com/download).